# Is there a WPF equaivalent to System.Windows.Forms.Screen?

Tags: wpf, desktop

I'm trying to create a WPF window that will encompass the entire Desktop working area. In WinForms I'd do this by getting the Union of all the bounds in `System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens`.

Is there an equivalent type or other mechanism to get the bounds of the entire desktop in WPF or do I need to use the WinForms type?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try SystemParameters.VirtualScreen* (Top, Left, Height, and Width) properties. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.virtualscreenheight(v=VS.100).aspx

Don't use winforms api because it doesn't take into account the fact that WPF's measurement units are not pixels. I came across this issue just recently because I'm losing my vision and have my monitor set to a higher dpi. The codebase I was working on used the Winforms Settings and the UI was larger than my screen.

If you're going to use the winforms api. Look at this blog post on [calculating the DPI factor](http://blogs.msdn.com/jaimer/archive/2007/03/07/getting-system-dpi-in-wpf-app.aspx).

Comment: Just to point it out bluntly:  this does _precisely_ what OP wanted, and nothing more.  Whereas `Screen` can enumerate each monitor separately, `VirtualScreen` is _only_ the total area.

Answer (score 16):

I have successfully used WpfScreenHelper 0.3.0.0, currently on Github or Nuget,
https://github.com/micdenny/WpfScreenHelper

It does what the .NET framework should have done so many years ago.
I needed to check if some coordinates exist on any screen in WPF, as in these:

- Very germane: [Determine if an open WPF window is visible on any monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434338/determine-if-an-open-wpf-window-is-visible-on-any-monitor)
- Forms-only and inadequate WPF suggestions: [Determining if a form is completely off screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987018/determining-if-a-form-is-completely-off-screen)

Answer (score 2):

Just use WinForms. I do not think there is a direct WPF equivalent.

Comment: Wrong there are WPF Equivalents. See my response.

Comment: Oh? Can WPF tell us about each monitor individually? Can WPF tell you which screen a window is on (like Screen.FromControl()?)

Comment: What if you have multiple monitors with not equal size? Is there any equivalent to handle this? and as Qwertie mentioned which screen it is?

Comment: How does such answers get up voted? This is no answer AT ALL.

Comment: The problem with importing winforms is that it becomes far too easy to accidentally reference winforms types instead of wpf types, which ends up polluting wpf code with non-portable cruft. All of a sudden there are literally two types for *everything*, one of them being an unwanted WInForms type. DON'T DO IT!!!

Answer (score 1):

You could try SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth and associated parameters.  That might not provide as good as a result as continuing with the WinForms API.

The only downside I can see with the WinForms type is an extra dependency and the larger working set related to that.

Comment: ... plus two types for EVERYTHING! Two Rectangles. Two Points. Two ....