# How to ensure my form is visible in C#?

Tags: window, positioning

I'm looking for a way to check to see that a window I am creating is visible and entirely on one monitor.  I have seen too many programs do nasty things when they try to restore their position and the place no longer exists and I don't want my program to be vulnerable to this.

How do I find the information on the actual layout of the monitors?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Determining if a form is completely off screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987018/c-sharp-determining-if-a-form-is-completely-off-screen)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Screen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8xzhd15.aspx) class contains a lot of functionality for this.

You should check for yourself if a form is outside the Bounds of the Screen, but this is pretty straightforward:

```
if (!Screen.GetWorkingArea(myWindow).Bounds.Contains(myWindow.Bounds)) {
   // Adjust location
}
```

Comment: That looks like it's the answer.  I apparently fed the wrong terms to Google.  I guess I was fixated on monitors instead of screens.

Comment: I was about to leave a nasty comment about multi-screen support - but then I noticed this in the MSDN documentation: "In multiple display environments where no display contains the specified control, the display closest to the control is returned." You win.

Answer (score 3):

Just a small syntax correction, or perhaps an update in Visual Studio 2012:

```
if (!Screen.GetWorkingArea(myWindow).Contains(myWindow.Bounds))
{
    //Adjust location
}
```